# Post to facebook page from facebook page tab app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I want to post activities from page tab app to my own facebook page. I referred many documents to post message to app.

My php code :

```
    $GLOBALS["facebook"] = new \Facebook_Facebook(array('appId'  => $facebook_app_id, 'secret' => $facebook_secret,));

    $page_info = $GLOBALS["facebook"]->api("/pageid?fields=access_token");
    print_r($page_info);die;
    if (!empty($page_info['access_token'])) {
        $args = array(
                'access_token' => $page_info['access_token'],
                'message' => 'TEST'
        );

        $postId = $facebook->api("/pageid/feed", "post", $args);
```

But pageinfo variable has only id. I'm not getting access_token. Any idea what else need to be done?

Comment: You need to login the user first to get an access_token

Comment: I guess to post in my page I need my page access token...not users. It is nothing to do with user if we check flow. It is purely from my app to my page. Am I wrong?

Comment: You get the page access token from a user access token

Answer (score 0):

We need `manage_pages` permission which we can get it using `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=client_app_id&client_secret=9ea3e2eff7c65b1fcf1a633da&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URL&scope=read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access,manage_pages.`

After that using above code we will get access token which can be used to publish to our page